# Excel VBA - More effective ways of writing Arrays

Tags: vba, excel

I successfully built a tool in excel VBA which can take data from a CJ74 report in SAP, consolidate it, and migrate it into a financial tool which we use in our Project office at work.

A second of the code uses arrays to pull data and transpose it into columns, this code works but I know it could perform better if written properly.  Current code is below, I would welcome suggestions to get this code working in one line.

```
Sub Array()
Dim DateStore As Variant
Dim actualcolumnsource As Long, lngcnt as long

lngCnt = 0
actualcolumnsource = SourceSheet.Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToRight).row

ReDim DateStore(0 To actualcolumnsource)
For lngCnt = LBound(DateStore, 1) To UBound(DateStore, 1)
    If lngCnt = 0 Then
        DateStore(lngCnt) = SourceSheet.Cells(5, lngCnt + 1).Value
    Else
        DateStore(lngCnt) = SourceSheet.Cells(5, lngCnt).Value
    End If
Next lngCnt
dumpsheet.Range("E2").Resize((UBound(DateStore) - LBound(DateStore)) + 1, 1).Value = _
                                                        Application.Transpose(DateStore)
lngCnt = 0
Erase DateStore

ReDim DateStore(0 To actualcolumnsource)
For lngCnt = LBound(DateStore, 1) To UBound(DateStore, 1)
    If lngCnt = 0 Then
        DateStore(lngCnt) = SourceSheet.Cells(5, lngCnt + 1).Column
    Else
        DateStore(lngCnt) = SourceSheet.Cells(5, lngCnt).Column
    End If
Next lngCnt
dumpsheet.Range("F2").Resize((UBound(DateStore) - LBound(DateStore)) + 1, 1).Value = _
                                                        Application.Transpose(DateStore)

lngCnt = 0
Erase DateStore


ReDim DateStore(0 To actualcolumntarget)
For lngCnt = LBound(DateStore, 1) To UBound(DateStore, 1)
    If lngCnt = 0 Then
        DateStore(lngCnt) = TargetSheet.Cells(5, lngCnt + 1).Value
    Else
        DateStore(lngCnt) = TargetSheet.Cells(5, lngCnt).Value
    End If
Next lngCnt
dumpsheet.Range("G2").Resize((UBound(DateStore) - LBound(DateStore)) + 1, 1).Value = _
                                                        Application.Transpose(DateStore)


lngCnt = 0
Erase DateStore


ReDim DateStore(0 To actualcolumntarget)
For lngCnt = LBound(DateStore, 1) To UBound(DateStore, 1)
    If lngCnt = 0 Then
        DateStore(lngCnt) = TargetSheet.Cells(5, lngCnt + 1).Column
    Else
        DateStore(lngCnt) = TargetSheet.Cells(5, lngCnt).Column
    End If
Next lngCnt
dumpsheet.Range("H2").Resize((UBound(DateStore) - LBound(DateStore)) + 1, 1).Value = _
                                                    Application.Transpose(DateStore)

lngCnt = 0
Erase DateStore

End Sub
```

Comment: This would be a great question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Not so great here; "improve this" code dumps aren't really the thing on SO. Also, not clear what you mean by "get this code working in one line".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Abandon the 1D array and use 2D Array.
This will also eliminate the use of `Application.Transpose` which has its limitations.
Consider below: (assuming you already got the `actualcolumnsource` variable)

```
ReDim DateStore(1 To actualcolumntarget, 0 To 3) ' explicit array dimensioning
For lngcnt = LBound(DateStore, 1) To Ubound(DateStore, 1)
    Datestore(lngcnt, 0) = SourceSheet.Cells(5, lngCnt).Value2
    Datestore(lngcnt, 1) = SourceSheet.Cells(5, lngCnt).Column
    Datestore(lngcnt, 2) = TargetSheet.Cells(5, lngCnt).Value2
    Datestore(lngcnt, 3) = TargetSheet.Cells(5, lngCnt).Column
Next
dumpsheet.Range("E2:H" & actualcolumntarget + 1) = DateStore
```

Array already explicitly dimensioned so the `If Statement` is not needed.
Also, that writes the value of A5, twice in the array.
`+1` is needed at the last line, since you started at 2nd row.
Also, I used `Value2`, that is faster than `Value` property.

Comment: @PootyToot Glad it did. If you'll continue working on range to array and vice versa, better to use 2D array specially if you already know the dimensions.

Comment: There is only one issue with it, the original solution managed to pick up dates in Column G, this line misses the date value.

Datestore(lngcnt, 2) = TargetSheet.Cells(5, lngCnt).Value2

Yet this line picks up the date

Datestore(lngcnt, 0) = SourceSheet.Cells(5, lngCnt).Value2

Comment: @PootyToot Ah that's not suppose to happen. Try using `Value`. But it's suppose to work both ways.

Comment: You wouldn't believe the number of times I've said that, VBA tends to throw a tonne of gotchas.  I suspect the reason why it isn't working is because the redimension of the array is missing.

This line here redimensioned the array to match the number of cells in the target column (always different to the source):  ReDim DateStore(0 To actualcolumntarget)

Comment: Just edited your response and changed the code slightly, it works now!  The target column results (27 cells) is longer than the source column results (5 cells).  I just replaced the redimension with the targetcolumn and it worked

Comment: @PootyToot Cool stuff. Good job in figuring it out. One more tip. If you can make your code shorter, that is better. Always.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74685/discussion-between-pootytoot-and-l42).